# Are miners eliminated in Proof of Authority?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, proof-of-authority

According to [this blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/04/01/ethereum-dev-roundup-q1/) by Vitalik on April 1st 2017, Ethereum will move from Proof of Work to Proof of Authority in 2018. He states:

> We have decided that the problem is too hard, and secure proof of
>   stake is almost certainly unachievable. Instead, we are now planning
>   to transition the Ethereum mainnet to proof of authority in 2018.

I was looking at getting into Ethereum mining, but now I am unclear what impact this decision has on mining profitability and risk.

I attempted to read [this](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225), and ended up in over my head. However, I found this quote under Proof-of-authority 101:

> For those not aware of how PoA works, it's a very simplistic protocol,
>   where instead of miners racing to find a solution to a difficult
>   problem, authorized signers can at any time at their own discretion
>   create new blocks.

It seems to be saying that signers are the new miners. Is mining even necessary under a proof of authority system?

As someone new to block chain technology and Ethereum this is a little confusing.

Comment: According to this blog post by Vitalik on **April 1st** 2017

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a joke.

However, Ethereum does eventually plan to move to Proof of Stake, which is intended to replace mining.

Comment: I thought it might be since it was April fools day, but it is written very convincingly.