# Will mining Ethereum be profitable after Proof of Stake/ Proof of Authority?

Tags: mining

What will actually happen when they move to Proof of Stake ? If I want to start mining with 8-10 rigs now would it be profitable if they move to Proof of State or POA ? In short...will I make money after that or should I move to other crypto currency ? Thanks

I am providing a link to another user who started a similar question: 
[Are miners eliminated in Proof of Authority?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/are-miners-eliminated-in-proof-of-authority/15083?noredirect=1#comment15778_15083)

Comment: I think this probably answers your questions (or the questions it's dupe'd to... ). Any help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/is-switching-to-proof-of-stake-pos-makes-gpu-mining-worthless?rq=1

Comment: I am a bit confused since I read that PoS won't happen and Ethereum will migrate to PoA. Yesterday I read that they are almost complete with phase one of PoS. However why would I want to give them my ...let's say 100...1000 or whatever coins of Ethereum when they will be blocked from accessing in some amount of time. If I start mining now, do I have to throw away my rigs after PoS has started. Yes,I know I can mine other currencies, but simply said, will I make money mining after PoS ? Does anyone have a simple answer ?

Comment: Ethereum isn't migrating to PoA. There are PoA testnets, but the mainnet will never be PoA.